# Web scraping using requests module gets stuck without cutting kernel python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am web scraping content from a list of urls and printing the text in python using the `bs4` and `requests` module. The problem is that the scraping always gets stuck on a random url without cutting.

Furthermore when I manually cut with `ctrl c` it doesn't properly cut as I can't seem to run any other code, as if something is going on in the background.

Before I **scrape** I check the response code is 200 and the code looks as such (this is the url it seems to get stuck on this time):

```
url = 'https://www.businessinsider.in/business/ecommerce/news/amazon-is-eyeing-india-startups-as-it-gears-up-for-a-fight-with-asia-richest-man-in-retail/articleshow/81773692.cms?utm_campaign=cityfalcon&utm_medium=cityfalcon&utm_source=cityfalcon'

response = requests.get(url)
if str(response) == '<Response [200]>':
    report = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml').text
print(report)
```

Does the requests module have a certain amount of times you can use it within an hour? Wouldn't anyone know how I could start to go about debugging a problem like this without any error?

Any further clarifications needed or code needed please let me know.

EDIT

This has happened again with a different URL. The response code was `<Response [403]>` for url= https://www.investing.com/news/stephens-stick-to-their-buy-rating-for-tyson-foods-2470535?utm_campaign=cityfalcon&utm_medium=cityfalcon&utm_source=cityfalcon

It also has got stuck on this one:

`<Response [200]>`
[https://www.benzinga.com/analyst-ratings/analyst-color/21/04/20568999/analysts-upgraded-amc-snap-united-airlines-and-tesla-in-the-past-week'](https://www.benzinga.com/analyst-ratings/analyst-color/21/04/20568999/analysts-upgraded-amc-snap-united-airlines-and-tesla-in-the-past-week%27)

Once again it won't let me interrupt and continue working. For the 403 error, it should just bypass the condition anyway so I really do not understand as there is no error it just keeps running?

Comment: cannot reproduce the error. i tried adding a loop and hit the same url 100 times. did not hang once.

Comment: @Yash No problem. I really don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I run it about 100 times, without any exceptions.

but one note,
it's not the pythonic way to check response status code like this

```py
if str(response) == '<Response [200]>':
```

Use this code instead.

```py
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Do staff
```